# Secure remote viewing of IP camera stream/recording

Tags: security, streaming, https, ip-camera

I am trying to setup internal camera to watch over an infirm elderly family member. I need to be able to view it from a remote connection. While researching, I noticed nearly every guide simply uses http and port 80 or some subscription closed source cloud app. Most cameras I find in different shops have lacking documentation, not even mentioning https.

I did find one guide where user has to install a root certificate on their machine for viewing. I imagine this is so that it will always accept cameras internal web servers SSL certificate. I would much rather prefer generating my own than using the provided one and add yet another 3rd party root certificate on my machine.

Is there an opensource solution that I can install on my own webhosting that can stream and keep recordings and allow me to securely connect to or download from? Any IP camera recommendations that support https and sending stream to remote server would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thank you!